# c# Как преобразовать число в шестнадцатеричный байт?

Tags: c#

Есть к примеру число 2010,
как из него получить байт 0x7da ? И именно байт, а не строчку.

Comment: [`Convert.ToByte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c7xhf79k(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: То ли вам число в строку надо пребразовать, то ли наоборот, строку в число, непонятно. Напишите хоть какой-нибудь псевокод, что бы понять, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: 0x7da это вообще-то не байт

Comment: Внутри компьютера всё хранится в битах/байтах независимо от того что выведено на экран. Т.е. `2010` и `0x7da` это одно и то же число и будет лежать в виде одного и того же набора битов `0000011111011010` (добавьте слева нужное количество нулей)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Думаю, Вы не совсем понимаете значение слова `байт`.

> Байт - единица измерения количества информации, равная 8 битам.

Тем самым `байт` принимает значение от `0` до `255`.
То, что написали Вы, является не "байтом", а обычным числом в его `16-ричном` представлении. Тем самым код:

```
int a = 2010;
int b = 0x7da;
Console.WriteLine(a == b); // true
```

Покажет Вам, что значения абсолютно идентичны. Различна лишь форма их записи.

---

Если Вам в коде необходимо записать число именно в таком формате, а также Вы используете IDE `Visual Studio`, то, нажав `ПКМ` по числу и выбрав графу `Быстрые действия и рефракторинг`, Вы обнаружите возможность перевода записанного числа в его `2-ичное`, `10-тичное` и `16-ричное`представление. 
Тем самым код:

```
int a = 2010;
```

`VS` поможет Вам превратить в:

```
int a = 0x7DA;
```

Или в:

```
int a = 0b11111011010;
```

И обратно

---

Если же Вы хотите преобразовать число в строку в виде его `16-ричного` представления, то код, к примеру, следующий:

```
int a = 2010;
string b = $"0x{Convert.ToString(a, 16)}";
Console.WriteLine(b); // 0x7da
```